# Makefile to build shared library

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I've been building a `C++11` library, and the number of header/source files has grown to the point where compiling programs invoking it, entails passing 20+ `.cpp` files to `g++`. I've been reading up on shared libraries and it seems to be the best solution.

However, as headers/source change frequently, I'm hoping to create a `makefile` that would automatically generate all the `.so` files from the headers and source.

To better demonstrate what I'm trying to do, I'll take one of my sub-libraries, `Chrono` and show how I would do this manually.

I first create the object files like so,

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -fPIC -g -c -Wall ../src/Chrono/cpp/DateTime.cpp
$ g++ -std=c++11 -fPIC -g -c -Wall ../src/Chrono/cpp/Schedule.cpp
$ g++ -std=c++11 -fPIC -g -c -Wall ../src/Chrono/cpp/Duration.cpp
$ g++ -std=c++11 -fPIC -g -c -Wall ../src/Chrono/cpp/DayCount.cpp
```

So that I now have `DateTime.o`, `Schedule.o`, `Duration.o`, and `DayCount.o` in the current directory. I then create the `.so` file,

```
$ g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libChrono.so.1 -o libChrono.so.1.0.1 DateTime.o Schedule.o Duration.o DayCount.o -lc
```

I then go,

```
$ rm ./*.o && ldconfig -n ./
```

So that my working directory now contains, `libChrono.so.1.0.1` and the symlink `libChrono.so.1`.

There are quite a few subdirectories I need to do this for, so you can see that this quickly grows inefficient whenever changes to headers/source are made. I would be grateful if anyone can help me design a makefile that accomplishes all this simply by invoking `make`.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Based on goldilock's advice and some digging, I managed to bang together:

```
CXX=g++
CFLAGS=-std=c++11 
TARGET=./lib/libChrono.so.1.0.1
CHRONODIR=./src/Chrono
CHRONOSRC=$(wildcard $(CHRONODIR)/cpp/*.cpp)
CHRONOOBJ=$(join $(addsuffix ../obj/,  $(dir $(CHRONOSRC))), $(notdir (CHRONOSRC:.cpp=.o)))

all: $(TARGET)
    @true

clean:
    @-rm -f $(TARGET) $(CHRONOOBJ)

./lib/libChrono.so.1.0.1: $(CHRONOOBJ)
    @echo "======================="
    @echo "Creating library file $@"
    @echo "======================="
    @$(CXX) -shared -Wl,-soname,$(join $(basename $@), .1) -o $@ $^ -l
    @echo "-- $@ file created --"

$(CHRONODIR)/cpp/../obj/%.o : $(CHRONOSRC)
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    @echo "============="
    @echo "Compiling $<"
    @$(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -fPIC -g -Wall -c $< -o $@
```

4 `.o` files are produced in `lib/` but I get multiple definition complaints from `ld`. Before I was compiling the object files separately, but this unwinds `CHRONOOBJ` on one line. Any ideas?

Comment: _'I would be grateful if anyone can help me design a makefile that accomplishes all this simply by invoking make.'_ Sorry no! As usual SO doesn't make up a code factory up to your service. Neither for c++ code, nor for makefile coding.

Comment: You have the commands you need, just put the in the makefile. If you don't know how to make a makefile at all, then this question is to broad. You might want to [search for makefile tutorials](https://www.google.se/search?q=makefile+tutorial&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=fEHJU-ibH4WA8Qf5joHoCA).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fortunately you included the origin of your problem:

> I've been building a C++11 library, and the number of header/source files has grown to the point where compiling programs invoking it, entails passing 20+ .cpp files to g++.

Because this reveals a potential [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  The straightforward solution to this is to put object files into an archive (aka. a *static* library) and use that.

GNU make has an [implicit rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html) for creating C++ `.o` files.  It amounts to this:

```
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $<
```

Meaning, if you `make DateTime.o` in a directory with a makefile that doesn't redefine this, it will make `DateTime.o`.  You may want to add things to `$(CXXFLAGS)` however, e.g.:

```
CXXFLAGS += -Wall -Wextra --std=c++11
```

If you intend to stick with the shared lib route, `-fPIC` can go there too.  That one line could be your entire makefile.

However, you also want to put these together, so you must first declare all the objects and a rule for combining them:

```
OBJS = DateTime.o Schedule.o Duration.o

libChrono.a: $(OBJS)
    ar crvs $@ $^
```

This last line (see `man ar`) creates the archive (libChrono.a) containing all the objects in `$(OBJS)`.  You can then use this with whatever program by placing it in the same directory (or a directory in the library path) and linking `-lChrono`.  Only the necessary parts will be extracted and compiled in.  This saves you having to maintain a shared lib in a system directory.

If you still think you need a shared lib, `$@` and `$^` are [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables); you can use similar methodology to create a `.so`, something along the lines of:

```
SO_FLAGS = -shared

libChrono.so.1.0.1: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(SO_FLAGS) -Wl,-soname,libChrono.so.1 -o $@ $^ -lc
```

If that is your first rule, `make` will take care of everything: building first the objects and then the library.  Notice this one has excluded your normal `$(CXXFLAGS)` to duplicate exactly the compiler line from the question.